# How to convert parsed string into enum type as an argument in java

Tags: java, parsing, enums

I am new to java and practicing parsing csv file. Now, I've successfully parsed the file into columns, but I need to convert the string into the enum type as an argument.

The file is like this:

```
Profession //the header
boxer
nurse
doctor
 .
 .
 .
```

I have an enum type `Profession`:

```
enum {BOXER,NURSE,DOCTOR,UNKNOWN,...,...,...}
```

And I've parsed the data like this:

```
ArrayList<String> csvContents = new ArrayList<String>();

try (BufferedReader csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));) {
        String headerLine = csvReader.readLine(); //get rid of the header

        while ((line = csvReader.readLine()) != null) { 
            csvContents.add(line);   
        }

        for (String csvLine : csvContents) {
            String[] data = csvLine.split("\\s*,\\s*"); // split by comma and remove redundant spaces
            String profession = data[0].toUpperCase(); // String type
            Person(Profession data[0], otherArgument); // need to be Profession enum type

    }
```

I've already known that I can get the value by doing this:

```
Profession.valueOf(data[0].toUpperCase);
```

But how can I convert this value into `Profession` enum type?
Any help or hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Woden, what do you mean by `Profession.valueOf(data[0].toUpperCase);`. You have already done it, `Profession p = Profession.valueOf(data[0].toUpperCase);`. No?

Comment: @jumping_monkey Thank you. I think I just get confused sometimes... I don't even know I've got the answer already. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Profession professionEnum = Profession.valueOf(data[0].toUpperCase);
```

this will give you enum type which you pass to your method as below:

```
Person(professionEnum, otherArgument);
```